# How to recover deleted folders or files (by shift+delete) from an NTFS partition

Tags: files, delete, restore

I have a 80 GB hdd in which Ubuntu is installed alongside windows. I also have a 500 GB hdd  having 3 partitions in which i store my data. Actually i mistakenly deleted a folder permanently in one of the partition which is of 381 GB. That folder had all the movies in it and it accounted for almost 200 GB space of that partition. Now i am in great trouble as all my data is lost. Please someone suggest me a simple tool to recover that folder and all the files in it because i am only 13 years old and don't understand Ubuntu much..!!

Comment: **Don't use this drive until you were able to recover your files.** How did you delete this folder? Did you delete it from Windows or was it from Ubuntu? First thing I would try: see if you can find it in the Trash. Else, can you boot into Windows for recovery? If not you may have to use command line. Would that be o.k?

Comment: yes that woud be o.k.
and i deleted this from ubuntu only by pressing the shift+delete key..

Comment: Using TestDisk, click through device and type to Advanced.. in partition selection, pay attention to the bottom for Undelete. Then select a different drive to save to. I believe its possible to write a script using fls from TestDisk to recover from a single directory if that is needed or when the TD single selection is tedious.. see this answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390174/346155

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two command line tools available for Ubuntu to recover deleted files on an NTFS partition:

- **ntfsundelete:** see details in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/206655/3940) and in [another answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59968/recover-accidentally-removed-files-on-ntfs-partition) here.

  [image: Install via the software center]
- **testdisk:** see a detailed [guide from CG-Security](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Undelete_files_from_NTFS_with_TestDisk)

  [image: Install via the software center]

---

Just to mention this in case you are uncomfortable with the command line. There is a graphical tool [NTFS undelete](http://www.ntfsundelete.com/) available for Windows only.

Comment: If the free methods do not work for you, you may want to consider DiskInternals Uneraser. I found Testdisk gave me an overwhelming list of files with numerical names so that it was not feasible for me to go through one at a time to identify each while NTFS undelete did not find all or even most of the files I knew were there. DI Uneraser did a really surprising job finding some files that had been deleted years ago. Just google it, I don't want to put up a commercial link on stackexchange. It does require a Winows OS though.