# How to Recover Permanently Deleted File from NTFS Partition?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, ntfs

Due to any reason my Seagate freeagent GO 500 GB hard disk drive failed and completed out of my reach. Having attempted numerous things in the course of recent day and attempting it on various operating systems internally and USB. I recently found that the partition has been erased and the drive is Became RAW.

Comment: Here a similar thread http://askubuntu.com/questions/219241/how-to-recover-deleted-folders-or-files-by-shiftdelete-from-an-ntfs-partition check that whether this helps.

Comment: I have applied various data recovery methods but all are useless. Please anyone can suggest me best method that can recover my data in secure manner. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Such recommendation requires that you list the various methods you unsuccessfully used.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read through this wiki post on data recovery:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Testdisk

and I suggest you try to recover your data using testdisk.

Answer (score 0):

`fdisk` (`sudo apt-get install fdisk`) can be used to see partition tables and make advance modification to them. I had the exact same problem with a disk and made a backup of my partition table with `fdisk`. (read `man fdisk` for more info)

Then I tried `testdisk` to recover my partition table and it worked like a charm. TestDisk is a fantastic product to recover partition tables.

But if you overwritten your partition table, odds are you won't be able to recover the partition and you're better off trying to recover files after formatting the disk to NTFS again.

[Official Ubuntu data recovery documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery)

[Official testdisk documentation](http://drehsen.com/compusectools/testdisk/testdisk/doc/testdisk.html)